# Matlab: Regex for removing consecutive white space and punctuation

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a string array that I need to clean up. For example I have:

```
textfile =

I would like to play in the woods on a shine bright day which comes soon enough.

I would like to play in the woods on a shine bright day which comes soon enough.
```

There are multiple consecutive spaces of which I want to eliminate. So another word, I want only 1 space to be between each word. Also I want to replace everything except characters, so no punctuations or any special characters that are not A-Z or a-Z.

For the second I tried:

```
regexprep(textfile,'[`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\|;:\''<,>.?/','')
```

But it doesn't replace the periods so I am assuming I did something wrong? Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could tolerate doing this in two passes you could first replace

```
\s+
```

With `' '` (single space), and then replace

```
[^A-Za-z ]
```

with nothing

(edited based on OP's comment - so this is now the correct order)

Comment: @user1234440 glad it works. I have updated the answer to reflect the correct order per your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a negated character class with what you want to preserve and replace it with an only space.

```
regexprep(textfile,'[^A-Za-z]+',' ')
```

Comment: both of these yield "I would like to play in the woods on a shine bright day which comes soon enoughI would like to play in the woods on a shine bright day which comes soon enough" where "enoughI" are together